# Solving ODE numerically - getting local truncation error

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Well I have NO idea how to do this or even where to start

Compute the order of magnitude of the local truncation error of the following time
integration scheme:
$$y_{n+1} = y_{n-1} + 2h f(y_n)$$

H is the step size (and $y_0$, $y_1$ would be the starting values)

The local truncation error can be written as $\bar{y}$ is the actual value of y at position n:
$$\epsilon _{i+1} = \bar{y}_{n+i} - y_{n+1}$$
This gives the order of magnitude $p$, where p is maximised in:
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow0} \frac{\epsilon_{n+1}}{h^p} < \infty$$

I've been told to use the tailor expansion of $y_{n+1}$ and $y_{n-1}$ though not sure what's meant by that and how that solves the problem.